# How to differentiate $y$ defined by the equation $\sin(x+y) =y^2 \cos x$?

Tags: calculus, implicit-differentiation

Given: $$\sin(x+y) = y^2 \cos x$$
find $dy/dx$.

$$\cos(x+y)(1+y')= \text{...product rule...}$$

how do we get the left one?

I am looking at the solution.
I tried replacing $\sin(x+y)$ with $\sin x \cos y+ \cos x \sin y$

Comment: i can't type 2 lines in the title, it would be messy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u=x+y$, then $$\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}x} = 1 + y'$$ by implicit differentiation. Now apply the chain rule on $\sin u$.

Comment: why du/dx isn't 1+0?

Comment: Because you're differentiating with respect to $x$.

Comment: i was thinking differentiating x+y with respect x so y = constant in this case, nevermind that...

I understand now

Comment: Great! Glad I helped! :-)

Comment: Differentiating with respect to $x$ can have two contexts, partial differentiation with respect to $x$ (keep other variables constant) and implicit differentiation with respect to $x$ (leave other variables as functions of $x$). Implicit differentiation gives the actual derivative, the partial derivative gives a different type of idea.

Comment: @JonathanHebert, I'm aware of that. Hence why I wrote "by implicit differentiation" in my answer. I avoided mentioning partial derivatives in case I confuse the OP.

Comment: I was addressing the OP, not you.